# Opening database that I created from cmd to Workbench

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I created a database of MariaDB from cmd. How can I open it in MySQL Workbench? I really need to see the source code of my work.

Comment: In the olden days before ides everything was done from cmd line and can still be done from command line search for SHOW, DESCRIBE and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/backup-and-recovery.html https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html And the mariadb equivalents - was there anything in particular you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you have successfully started a mariadb on your system, you should be able to create a new session in MySQL Workbench and connect to localhost:3306.

It should be exactly the same as connecting to a MySQL database, more detailed instructions can be found here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-wizard-connection.html